# Correct pronouns with participial phrases

Tags: pronouns, participial-phrases

In reference to a photo: There’s Bill and I on the mound, he having walked the batter, I handing him the ball...

he/his/him having walked

I/me handing him

Did I get the right pronouns in the above sentence? If not, which pronouns are best? Explanations most appreciated.

Comment: It's just a caption, don't sweat it. But I'd prefer, "There's Bill and me on the mound after he walked the batter and I handed him the ball."

Comment: There are omitted words (eg Yosef's 'after', perhaps a 'we') so matching cases doesn't make sense. But even the best choice (he/his/him ...I/me) of pronouns would leave you with something even Jeeves' eyebrows would rise at. Hyperformal and captions don't mix. Yosef's alternative is fine (assuming 'walked the batter' is an acceptable colonialism. Colloquialism. Baseball usage.)

Comment: This is not a caption. It's within narrative text.

Comment: There's a lot of things there that are questionable. Region and formality will have an impact, and you need to give more information on those. "There's" is colloquial and pedants would prefer "There are". "There we are, Bill and me" sounds better to me, but I'm sure other people will differ. "There's us" is certainly not uncommon (in some places).

Comment: I am editing a memoir. In the draft, the sentence reads, "There's Bill and me on the mound, him having walked the batter, me handing him the ball." I realize that it should instead be "There are Bill and I" but choosing not to go that route because the author and readership will likely find it stilted. I also changed "him" to "he" and "me" to "I" ... I suppose I should recommend a rewrite all around on this one.

Comment: "There are Bill and I " would not be idiomatic and it sounds horrible. "There's Bill and me/I” sounds so much better!